# How to create Android Application with Phonegap?

Tags: android, xml, image

How to `Installing` and configuring `PhoneGap for Android mobile development` with Eclipse.
can i get sample phonegap projects with android.

pls provide Phonegap tutorial or pdf files.

Comment: search 'phonegap android tutorial' into google....

Comment: -1 Hey man we should write a book in order to answer your question. It's not a question.

Comment: Just a google search for the same or exploring docs.phonegap.com would have helped you

Comment: first you should use worlds best search engine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit Phonegap website and look around. They have everything available on their website.

This will help you getting started.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android